# How to receive and play back a SHOUTcast audio stream on the mac or iphone?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, macos, shoutcast

Are there solutions in C or Objective-C to receive and play back SHOUTcast audio streams on the mac or iphone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement an M3U/PLS parser (which is just a text list of MP3 streams) and use the code here to play the MP3's

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can take a look at [FreeStreamer](https://github.com/muhku/FreeStreamer).